# How do I best install Ubuntu in a certain language with a keyboard layout specific to another language?

Tags: installation, keyboard-layout, language-support

I am installing Ubuntu 13.10: I want to use it in an English spoken environment, but my keyboard layout is an “exotic” one specific to French (Bépo Dvorak-way).

Until now, what I used to do was the following:

- install Ubuntu in French
- during the installation, choose my keyboard layout (Bépo Dvorak-way)
- after installation, change the language to English and remove all French translation packages.

Is there a better way?

Note: in the past, this seemed to be the best method due to the installer limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install in English.

At step 6 out of 8 of the installation, you will have the opportunity to set up the desired layout. This is totally independent from the environment language you selected before.

[image: Screenshot of step 6 out of 8]

Comment: this is the best way, hopefully you don't need to change between layouts because 13.10 has a nasty bug about it:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1218322

Comment: Do you really need to start a live session first? As far as I remember, you are in any case able to select the keyboard layout at installation irrespective of which language was selected.

Comment: This is indeed a much better option. If you confirm it and put it as answer, I'll select it as the accepted one, Gunnar.

Comment: @Agmenor: I proposed an edit of your answer instead. ;-)